Do I use the present perfect tense correctly?
Do I use the present perfect tense in the following conversations correctly?
Example 1
A: So, you didn’t see anything unusual in your neighborhood, did you?
B: I’ve already told you. I have stayed at the hotel for six days. I didn’t know about anything going on back in my neighborhood.
Example 2
A: Dude, where are you?
B: I am in the classroom.
A: What? Why?
B: Miss Chen told me not to leave. I have stayed here for two hours.
I think the first one is fine and the second one should be replaced with “have been staying.” Am I right?

There's no need to use the verb stay at all here. It's redundant in this context because we already know you've been told "not to leave", which is synonymous with staying.  So, all you need to say is "I've been here for two hours." - It's best to avoid repeating things when you don't have to.

The second one is fine.
You would say I have stayed/been staying at the hotel for six days if someone at the hotel was questioning you. In your scenario, it appears that B is being questioned about events hear his home while he was away. He would probably say I have been staying at a hotel for six days, or most likely I've been away for six days, staying at a hotel.

Is “I have stayed here for two hours” fine?

I told you that it was (that's what I meant by 'the second one').
